# solution for designing the hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have timesheet table in the database.
Timesheet id has been given  autoincrement  as primary key. 
There are other coloumns taskNo,Taskphase,taskdescription,etc as well in the timesheet table.
Each time before the timesheet entry is saved, I wanted to check the value of taskNo,and taskphase in the table.
If the value is same as of the new timesheet entry it should not allow to save. That means the checking
the duplicate entry of taskNo and taskphase.

First I thought to design entity as composite primary key(taskno taskphase). But I gave up that attempt  as these columns might be needed to edit.

Which is the best way of doing this kind of designing in hibernate?

Comment: Looks like this post has the answer you require http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786941/best-way-to-detect-duplicates-when-using-spring-hibernate-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can go with two approaches broadly

1) Let the database do the uniqueness checking, just put in a unique constraint on the column, when you insert a duplicate value, the database throws an error which you can propagate to the UI.

2) The application does the validation, you might need to read in all the taskNo's and taskphases and then loop through them to find if the newly inserted value is a duplicate or not.

If the no of rows are very large consider using some form of lazy loading from the database, like using a resultset or the like.

Answer (score 0):

u may try to add a validate interface before commit save.
like:

```
`findByTaskNoAndTaskPhase(String taskNo, String taskphase);`
```

do want u really want base on the result of interface.